# Web application could not be started

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I trying to use apache2 and mod passenger to run my rails application.
My setup is working fine when i use ubuntu 12.04.
Now i have updated to 14.04 and trying to get my application running.
but i always get the following long error.

```
/home/sandeep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG]
Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0057 p:---- s:0163 b:0163 l:000162 d:000162 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0056 p:---- s:0161 b:0161 l:000160 d:000160 CFUNC  :new
c:0055 p:0099 s:0158 b:0156 l:000155 d:000155 METHOD /home/sandeep/.rvm/gems/ruby- 2.1.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67
c:0054 p:0090 s:0147 b:0146 l:000145 d:000145 CLASS  /home/sandeep/.rvm/gems/ruby-   2.1.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:17
c:0053 p:0011 s:0144 b:0144 l:000143 d:000143 CLASS  /home/sandeep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12
c:0052 p:0074 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 TOP    /home/sandeep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:9
c:0051 p:---- s:0140 b:0140 l:000139 d:000139 FINISH
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot pin point exactly where the problem is with information you have given, however [there is a guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452809/how-to-install-ruby-1-8-7-back-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-upgrade) on how to reinstall ruby, check if you are doing something different.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for reply, I am using ruby 2.1.1 and I also re-installed it after upgrade to 14.04.
I have also reinstalled apache2 and passenger mod.
I have installed ruby using rvm. 
Please tell me what more info you need.

Comment: @Sandeeproop Here's an article on how to fix segmentation errors http://sysadmin.carlusgg.com/?p=197, my best guess would be you're missing some library that your project is dependent on.

Comment: I getting ruby 2.1.1 segmentation fault

Comment: any solution got? please specify. I am facing same issue.